# Disable auto-escaping when creating an HTML file with PrintWriter

Tags: java, html, printwriter

I don't know why this is so much harder than expected.

I'm trying to create an HTML file with Java, and it is not working. The code creates a file, but the contents are not what I inputted.

My simplified code is as follows:

```
File file = new File("text.html");
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(file);
    out.write("<b>Hello World!</b>");
} catch (Exception e) {    }
out.close();
```

Instead of the contents "**Hello World!**", the HTML file contains the escaped form "<b>Hello World!</b>". When I open the file with TextWrangler, I see that Java has automatically escaped all my angle brackets into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which breaks all the formatting and is NOT what I want.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: The PrintWriter will just write the "<b>Hello World!</b>" into file. You should open an HTML file with a web browser, not an editor, so you will get the "Hello World!" only.

Comment: @user27149 That's not what I'm asking. In my case, PrintWriter is automatically escaping all angle brackets into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which is breaking all my tags.

Comment: I think that's TextWrangler did the automatically escaping... Java will not do it for you. May be you can try open the file with another editor, such as notpad++, which shows the right content on my computer..

Comment: @user27149 I opened the file in Chrome and it showed all my `<b>` tags as plaintext instead of, well, boldface. Only when I opened it in an editor like TextWrangler did I realize that Java had escaped all my brackets into `&lt;`s.

Comment: This is really weird... `<` and `>` is special in HTML, but they are just normal characters in Java.  And your code works just fine on my computer.. May be you can post more details? IDE settings?

Comment: @user27149 I reinstalled Eclipse and it stopped. It had been acting really weird lately, maybe I touched something while messing around with the settings?

Comment: well, it could be. I'm using IntelliJ and can not reproduce the problem..